# Problem to put data in UITableView

Tags: iphone, objective-c

i write this code

```
- (void)requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
{
    // Use when fetching text data
    NSString *responseString = [request responseString];

    dataToDisplay = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    //NSString *myJSON = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:responseString];

    NSDictionary *json    = [responseString JSONValue];
    Status *statut = [[Status alloc] init];
    statut.flyNumber = [json objectForKey:@"flynumber"];
    statut.ftatuts = [json objectForKey:@"fstatuts"];
    statut.escDepart = [json objectForKey:@"escdepart"];
    statut.escArrival = [json objectForKey:@"escarrival"];
    statut.proArrival = [json objectForKey:@"proarrival"];
    statut.proDepart = [json objectForKey:@"prodepart"];
    statut.estDepart = [json objectForKey:@"estdepart"];
    statut.estArrival = [json objectForKey:@"estarrival"];
    statut.realDepart = [json objectForKey:@"realdepart"];
    statut.realArrival = [json objectForKey:@"realarrived"];

    [dataToDisplay addObject:statut];
    NSLog(@"ok");
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{

    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return [dataToDisplay count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    // Configure the cell...
    NSLog(@"1 ok");
    Status *statut2 = [dataToDisplay objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSLog(@"2 ok");
    cell.textLabel.text =  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ - %@",statut2.flyNumber,statut2.ftatuts];
    NSLog(@"3 ok");

    return cell;
}
```

The problem that the table still empty . And i don't have "ok 1" message in the console .
This is my controller .h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "ASIHTTPRequest.h"
#import "JSON.h"
#import "Status.h"

@interface StatusTableViewController : UITableViewController {
    NSString * Flynumber;   
    NSMutableArray *dataToDisplay;
}
@property(retain,nonatomic) IBOutlet NSString * Flynumber;
@end
```

i added `[self.tableView reloadData];` and it work .
[image]

But how to put each result on a line (cell) ?

Comment: Have you set the [datasource](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITableView/dataSource) of the table view?

Comment: No but now i tried to add @property(nonatomic, assign) id<UITableViewDataSource> datasource; and synthetise it in .m but still don't work

Comment: maybe you should work through some documentation: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone.html

Comment: Thank You but i alwayse don't understand :/ i even watch a video for how to do this ... I will post it in a new question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To execute a reload you have to execute :

```
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

at the end of the requestFinished: function

Comment: @Mehdi : if it works don't forget to vote up and/or accept the answer to notify the problem is solved.

Answer (score 1):

provided you have set everything else correctly, would you try and execute a `reloadData` at the end of `- (void)requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request`?

Comment: Sorry but i don't kwnow how to excute a reload :(

Answer (score 0):

Does your controller (?) conform to the `UITableViewDelegate` and `UITableViewDataSource` protocols?

```
@interface YourController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource> {...}
```

If yes, check to make sure you've set the `dataSource` property. Typically, this is set to `self`.

Comment: i don't think . I added my controllrt .h in the post